# Tengo un problema con mi Javascript y PHP expand y limitar caracteres

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo este Javascript

```
function expandContent() {
    var shortContent = document.getElementById('short-content');
    var fullContent = "<?php echo $content_product_1 ?>";

    shortContent.innerHTML = fullContent; 
    var readMoreButton = shortContent.nextElementSibling;
    readMoreButton.innerHTML = 'LEIA MENOS'; 
    readMoreButton.onclick = contractContent; 
}

function contractContent() {
    var shortContent = document.getElementById('short-content');
    var limitChars = "<?php echo $limit_chars ?>;" 
    var shortContentText = shortContent.innerHTML;

    shortContent.innerHTML = shortContentText.substr(0, limitChars) + '...'; 
    var readMoreButton = shortContent.nextElementSibling;
    readMoreButton.innerHTML = 'LER MAIS'; 
    readMoreButton.onclick = expandContent;
}
```

Y tengo este PHP

```
      <?php 
    
    $rapidodc = get_field("productos", $post->ID);
    $limit_chars = 200; 
    
?>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach($rapidodc as $carregamiento){ 
      $img_product_1 = $carregamiento["img_product_1"];
      $title_product_1 = $carregamiento["title_product_1"];
      $content_product_1 = $carregamiento["content_product_1"];
      

    ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div>
          <img src="<?php echo $img_product_1["url"]; ?>" alt="">
        </div>
        <h1 class="extraboldd my-3"><?php echo $title_product_1; ?></h1>
        <div>
        <?php 
            if (strlen($content_product_1) > $limit_chars) { // si el contenido es más largo que el límite permitido
                $short_content = substr($content_product_1, 0, $limit_chars) . '...'; // cortamos el contenido
                echo '<p id="short-content">' . $short_content . '</p>'; // imprimimos el contenido corto
                echo '<button onclick="expandContent()">LER MAIS</button>'; // agregamos un botón para expandir el contenido
            } else {
                echo '<p>' . $content_product_1 . '</p>'; // si el contenido no es más largo que el límite permitido, lo imprimimos completo
            }        
        ?>
        </div> 
      </div>      
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Estoy utilizando Wordpress y plugin Advance custom field donde tengo una variable que se llama $content_product_1 y quiero limitar ese contenido y que tenga un botón de leer mas y cuando hagas click salga otro de ver menos así cuando hagas click en cada uno haga su respectiva función expandir y devolver a su estado original

Comment: Solo apuntar que es Javascript, todo unido ;-)

Comment: no entendi a lo que te refieres pero muchas gracias ya solvente

Comment: El nombre es Javascript (unido), tu lo escribiste Java script (separado).

Comment: jajajaj vale vale gracias no mames pense que era otra cosa

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la respuesta es mas sencillo de lo que parece,

hice esta función mas fácil.

```
function AddReadMore() {
    
    var carLmt = 200;
   
    var readMoreTxt = "  LER MAIS";
   
    var readLessTxt = " LEIA MENOS";


    
    $(".addReadMore").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(".firstSec").length)
            return;

        var allstr = $(this).text();
        if (allstr.length > carLmt) {
            var firstSet = allstr.substring(0, carLmt);
            var secdHalf = allstr.substring(carLmt, allstr.length);
            var strtoadd = firstSet + "<span class='SecSec'>" + secdHalf + "</span><span class='readMore'  title='Click to Show More'>" + readMoreTxt + "</span><span class='readLess' title='Click to Show Less'>" + readLessTxt + "</span>";
            $(this).html(strtoadd);
        }

    });

    $(document).on("click", ".readMore,.readLess", function() {
        $(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
    });
}
$(function() {
    
    AddReadMore();
});
```

En PHP queda de esta manera

```
 <?php 
    
    $rapidodc = get_field("productos", $post->ID);
    $limit_chars = 200; 
    
?>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach($rapidodc as $carregamiento){ 
      $img_product_1 = $carregamiento["img_product_1"];
      $title_product_1 = $carregamiento["title_product_1"];
      $content_product_1 = $carregamiento["content_product_1"];
      

    ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div>
          <img src="<?php echo $img_product_1["url"]; ?>" alt="">
        </div>
        <h1 class="extraboldd my-3"><?php echo $title_product_1; ?></h1>
        
        <div class="addReadMore showlesscontent"> <p><?php echo $content_product_1; ?></p> </div>
        
      </div>      
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

y el CSS es

```
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .SecSec,
.addReadMore.showlesscontent .readLess {
    display: none;
}

.addReadMore.showmorecontent .readMore {
    display: none;
}

.addReadMore .readMore,
.addReadMore .readLess {
   font-weight: 400;
   margin-left: 2px;
   color: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 35px;
   margin-top: 22px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4061AB 0%, #25B474 100%);
   cursor: pointer;
   width: 38%;
   display: flex;
   padding: 10px 0px;
   justify-content: center;

}
.addReadMore .readMore:hover,
.addReadMore .readLess:hover {
   
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #25B474 0%, #4061AB 100%);
    
}

.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .SecSec,
.addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .readLess {
    display: block;
}
```